# Tomcat Migration effects on web.xml and struts-config.xml

Tags: tomcat, migration

What changes should i have to do in configuration file so that my struts project work properly in tomcat 6 and tomcat 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java EE is fairly backward-compatible.

Your application's `WEB-INF/web.xml` should not have to change at all.

Nothing changes with Struts.

Always remember to test vigorously with any new container version. There are a few things that have changed that don't affect `web.xml`, but they might affect your application. Specifically, some of the behaviors of HTTP cookies have changed.

I would highly recommend that you skip both Tomcat 6 *and* 7, and head straight for Tomcat 8.5 or even Tomcat 9.